# Why is chrome throwing error on my JS but works fine in IE FF Android and Safari?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an order form of sorts with conditional divs. When a user clicks on a yes/no radio button a new div is to be displayed.
In all browsers except for chrome it works fine. But in Chrome when a user selects a yes/no radio button, no new div is displayed and console throws the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at displayQuestion (conditional.js:3)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Here is the offending HTML:

```
<label>
<input type="radio" id="yestub" name="walltile1" value="yes" 
onchange="displayQuestion(this.value, 2)" />Yes
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" id="notub" name="walltile1" value="no" 
onchange="displayQuestion(this.value, 2)" />No
</label>
<div id="yesQuestion2" style="display:none;"><br/>
 <!-- some form fields -->
</div>
 <div id="noQuestion2" style="display:none;"><br/>
Ok Thank you!
</div>
```

Here is the related JS:

```
function displayQuestion(answer, n) {

document.getElementById(answer + 'Question' + n).style.display = "block";

if (answer == "yes") {

document.getElementById('noQuestion' + n).style.display = "none";

} 
else if (answer == "no") {

document.getElementById('yesQuestion' + n).style.display = "none";

}

}
```

Why is this returning null to chrome but works fine in other browsers?

Also made a fiddle and can't get it to work there..
https://jsfiddle.net/fiveonadub/mq7erj9f/3/

Can someone please help me to understand what is happening here.

Also I am new to stackoverflow so if I asked this question wrong please tell me how I can do better.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is just an issue with the order things are loading in CodePen.  In the Javascript window/panel, click the dropdown and select function "No wrap - bottom of `<body>`" and re-rerun your code.

Comment: Respectfully, your solution works, but it's actually a closure issue, not an order issue.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept the answer here that best helps you.  I recommend @David784's answer because it explains _why_ my answer works and is probably more valuable to your understanding in the long run. :)

Comment: So,
I am sure that you explained it properly, and I almost get it.
But I do not understand how to modify the code to make it work.
I hate to ask you to code it for me because I want to understand how it works for future endeavors ..
I do not understand how to add window properties inside of a closure.
Maybe you know of some good tutorials on the subject

Comment: You aren't adding window properties inside a closure.  You are making your function a property of the window to _avoid_ a closure.  Just follow the directions in @David784's answer and it works.

Comment: I added the window.displayQuestion = to my script but I still get the same error

Comment: cleared cache and it works great now...was still loading old script I think.. :/
Thank you. I have a better understanding after reading tons of stuff that you pointed to

Answer (score 0):

It's a closure issue. As @jmargolisvt points out in his answer, it's important to look in the JavaScript dropdown in jsfiddle, which in your example shows "Load Type: On Load."

This means that all of your code is inside of a function that is associated with an event handler. Which means that your function definition is inside what is called a `closure`, and is thus not a global function.

There are two ways to solve this: First, again as @jmargolisvt says, putting this in a `No wrap` script tag (top or bottom, either would work) will suffice to make this a `global` function.

The other possibility involves knowing what makes a variable or function "global" in the first place: all globals in a web browser are properties of the `window` object. And you can add window properties inside of any closure, such as:

```
window.displayQuestion = function(answer, n) { /* ... */ }
```

This is the most explicit solution, since it will always work, regardless of closures.